# How to merge two tables and transpose rows to columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have these two tables:

**T1**

```
id  x       y
8   42      1.9
9   30      1.9
```

**T2**

```
id  signal
8   55
8   56  
8   59
9   57
9   58  
9   60
```

The goal is to get the new table T3:

```
id  x       y       s1      s2      s3
8   42      1.9     55      56      58
9   30      1.9     57      58      60
```

If I do this operation, then it only performs merging without transposing:

```
pd.merge(T1, T2, on=['id'])
```

How to create columns `s1`, `s2` and `s3`, each corresponding to a row (the number of rows per `id` is always fixed and equal to 3)?

Comment: please pay attention at @unutbu's solution - it should be much faster compared to mine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

as @Jeff has written in his comment @ubuntu's solution should be faster and more idiomatic compared to mine:

```
In [40]: T1.merge(
   ....:     T2.pivot_table(index='id',
   ....:                    values='signal',
   ....:                    columns='s' + T2.groupby(['id'])['signal'].cumcount().astype(str))
   ....:       .reset_index()
   ....: )
Out[40]:
   id   x    y  s0  s1  s2
0   8  42  1.9  55  56  59
1   9  30  1.9  57  58  60
```

**OLD answer:**

you can do it this way:

```
In [209]: %paste
(t1.set_index('id')
   .join(t2.groupby('id')['signal']
           .apply(lambda x: x.tolist())
           .apply(pd.Series))
   .reset_index()
)
## -- End pasted text --
Out[209]:
   id   x    y   0   1   2
0   8  42  1.9  55  56  59
1   9  30  1.9  57  58  60
```

Explanation:

group `T2` by `id` and "collect" all corresponding signals into lists

```
In [211]: t2.groupby('id')['signal'].apply(lambda x: x.tolist())
Out[211]:
id
8    [55, 56, 59]
9    [57, 58, 60]
Name: signal, dtype: object
```

expand lists to columns

```
In [213]: t2.groupby('id')['signal'].apply(lambda x: x.tolist()).apply(pd.Series)
Out[213]:
     0   1   2
id
8   55  56  59
9   57  58  60
```

and finally join both tables by index `id`

PS if you want to rename all numeric columns, you can do it this way (assuming that you saved result into the `rslt` DF):

```
In [224]: rslt.columns = [c if c in ['id','x','y'] else 's{}'.format(c) for c in rslt.columns.tolist()]

In [225]: rslt
Out[225]:
   id   x    y  s0  s1  s2
0   8  42  1.9  55  56  59
1   9  30  1.9  57  58  60
```

Comment: Could you please briefly comment the logic behind this code?

Comment: @Klue, i've added a brief explanation to my answer - please check

Comment: just FYI, using apply like this is non-idiomatic & non-performant. Using reshaping operators like @ubuntu soln is much better.

Answer (score 3):

Yet another way is to use [groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html)/[cumcount](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html)/[pivot](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html):

```
import pandas as pd
T1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [8, 9], 'x': [42, 30], 'y': [1.9, 1.9]})
T2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9], 'signal': [55, 56, 59, 57, 58, 60]})
T2['col'] = 's' + T2.groupby(['id'])['signal'].cumcount().astype(str)
T2 = T2.pivot(index='id', columns='col', values='signal').reset_index()
result = pd.merge(T1, T2)
print(result)
```

yields

```
   id   x    y  s0  s1  s2
0   8  42  1.9  55  56  59
1   9  30  1.9  57  58  60
```

---

The main trick is to use `groupby/cumcount` to add a per-group cumulative count to T2:

```
In [81]: T2['col'] = 's' + T2.groupby(['id'])['signal'].cumcount().astype(str); T2
Out[81]: 
   id  signal col
0   8      55  s0
1   8      56  s1
2   8      59  s2
3   9      57  s0
4   9      58  s1
5   9      60  s2
```

Then `pivot` can be used to reshape `T2` into (or at least close to) the desired form:

```
In [82]: T2 = T2.pivot(index='id', columns='col', values='signal').reset_index(); T2
Out[82]: 
col  id  s0  s1  s2
0     8  55  56  59
1     9  57  58  60
```

and `result` can be obtained by merging:

```
In [83]: pd.merge(T1, T2)
Out[83]: 
   id   x    y  s0  s1  s2
0   8  42  1.9  55  56  59
1   9  30  1.9  57  58  60
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my way of using `groupby` and `unstack`:

```
df = df1.merge(df2.groupby('id')['signal'].apply(lambda x: x.reset_index(drop=True)).unstack().reset_index())

df
Out[63]: 
   id   x    y   0   1   2
0   8  42  1.9  55  56  59
1   9  30  1.9  57  58  60
```

If I separate them:

```
df2t = df2.groupby('id')['signal'].apply(lambda x: x.reset_index(drop=True)).unstack().reset_index()

df2t
Out[59]: 
   id   0   1   2
0   8  55  56  59
1   9  57  58  60

df = df1.merge(df2t)

df
Out[61]: 
   id   x    y   0   1   2
0   8  42  1.9  55  56  59
1   9  30  1.9  57  58  60
```