# Merging and transposing columns in Python gives TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'datetime.datetime'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, transpose

I will give a minimum sample of the two dataframe, Search_Exits and Page_Exits that I am trying to merge/transpose and the code I am using.

```
Search_Exits

Search_Term    No._of_Searches_before     %_Search_Exits_before
hello           10                        .070
goodbye         100                       .030



Page_Exits

Search_Term    Exit_Pages_actual          Ratios
hello          /store/car                 0.30
hello          /store/b2b                 0.30
hello          /store/catalog/product/12  0.40
goodbye        /store/car                 1.00
```

the result I would like to see here is:

```
Search_Term    No._of_Searches_before  %_Search_Exits_before   /store/car /store/catalog/product12 /store/catalog/product23   /store/b2b

hello          10                    .070                       0.30             0.40                       0.00                        0.30   
goodbye        100                   .030                       1.00             0.00                       0.00                        0.00
```

I have tried all 3 versions given in the answer from this stackoverflow question:[How to merge two tables and transpose rows to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37787289/how-to-merge-two-tables-and-transpose-rows-to-columns) but get the identical error message for all of them, I have attempted the following:

```
version 1

df = Search_Exits.merge(Page_Exits.groupby('Search_Term')['Exit_Pages_actual'].apply(lambda x: x.reset_index(drop=True)).unstack().reset_index())

version 2

Search_Exits.merge(Page_Exits.pivot_table(index='Search_Term', values='Ratios',columns='Exit_Pages_actual' + Page_Exits.groupby(['Search_Term'])['Exit_Pages_actual'].cumcount().astype(str)).reset_index())

version 3

(Search_Exits.set_index('Search_Term').join(Page_Exits.groupby('Search_Term')['Ratios'].apply(lambda x: x.tolist()).apply(pd.Series)).reset_index())
```

All 3 of these give me the following error, so I don't know what to do, if anyone can help:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 
'datetime.datetime'
```

UPDATE:

So I tried doing the same thing on a simulated dataset that I myself created and I no longer get the error message (so I guess I don't know what is causing that problem in the data) however I have 2 things that are currently occurring differently from how I want them to occur. Firstly, the newly generated columns are not being labeled with the corresponding "Exit_Pages_actual" that I wanted them to be labeled as. Secondly, each column does not represent the Ratios that should only be attributed to that particular "Exit_Pages_actual" so I was wondering what I should do with the code to change it for it to work like I want it to? Currently, with my new dataset the rest is something along the lines of:

```
Search_Term    No._of_Searches_before  %_Search_Exits_before  0    1    2  3 

hello          10                     .07                    0.3   0.3  0.4 NaN                                       
goodbye        100                    .03                    NaN   1.0  NaN
```

NaN

Comment: Hmmm, it seems there is some datetime column, but in sample is not...

Comment: right, I don't know why? There was a column with dates but I deleted it from the dataframe so I am not sure what the issue is?

Comment: @mkheifetz Did you do `df = df.drop('DateCol', 1)`? With the reassignment.

Comment: Or `df.drop('DateCol', axis=1, inplace=True)` without assignment ;)

Comment: I deleted the column that has dates by del Search_Exits['Date'] but that was before showing the 2 dataframes that I have a sample of, that's why I didn't even include it

Comment: @mkheifetz - Maybe error is something else, do you compare something? e.g. column or dataframe?

Comment: @mkheifetz - is possible show all rows of code?

Comment: Not sure I follow your question? I am trying to merge the 2 dataframes but transpose all the columns in "Exit_Pages_actual" to be vertical and the accompanying Ratios to show up for them, it might create a whole bunch of new columns because there are many different types of "Exit_Pages_actual", but I would imagine that would not be an issue?

Comment: Sure there is almost no code before what I posted on here, I just imported the excel file using .read_excel and then did: del Search_Exits['Date']

Comment: OK, I think it is some data related problem. Is possible upload your data to dropbox or gdocs or send me to my email in my profile if data not confidental?

Comment: I wish I could do that but it is confidential company data so I will not be able to do that. But it is data that I pulled straight from Google Analytics if that tells you anything at all, I am not sure? What makes you think something is wrong with the data?

Comment: Hmmm, then try anonymize data - rewrite numbers and text only. Because I think with your sample is not possible simulate your error.

Comment: yea I am going to do that out now, test it out and I guess I can email you if I still have the error with fake data, where can I reach out?

Comment: Check my profile, there is my email.

Comment: But please first check if your sample data return error, because hard simulate it ;) Thanks.

Comment: hey, so I did what you said, created an artificial dataset, reran the code and it no longer gave me the error message. However, it does 2 things with the code differently from what I would like. I updated my question. It does not label the newly created columns and it puts some values in the columns that should be in a different column instead.

Comment: @jezrael so it looks like I have another follow up question to all of this. So I got everything I wanted to work on my simulated dataset, but when I try it on the following code on the real dataset, I get an error: Page_Exits = Page_Exits.pivot(index='Search_Term', columns='Exit_Pages_actual', values='Ratios').reset_index() The error is: TypeError: 'values' is not ordered, please explicitly specify the categories order by passing in a categories argument. Do you know what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it looks like I figured out what I wanted using a pivot table:

```
Page_Exits = Page_Exits.pivot(index='Search_Term', 
columns='Exit_Pages_actual', values='Ratios').reset_index()
```

followed by a regular merge using pd.merge....

Comment: Can you send me your csv with sample data ? Because it is hard find problem without data... sure, remove confidental data, 4- 5 rows is super. Only need demonstrate your new problems... or try upgrade pandas, maybe ut jelp. Good luck!

Comment: Can I send you the file that works with simulated data? The thing is, I can't send the actual file since it has real data, even if its only a small sample.

Comment: it seems like it does not like other operations on the real file either, I just tried .pivot_table, which works well on my simulated file, but on the real file, it gives me a Memory Error

Comment: Yes, pivot table is really memory consumed operation, so if large data it is possible :(