# Pivot table error "Can't assign to operator"

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, data-handling

I get this error when running the code below 'Can't assign to operator'

```
df_2 = pd.pivot_table(df, index = df.columns[~df.columns.str.startswith('A')],
                         values = df.columns[ df.columns.str.startswith('A')])
```

I want to aggregate on all columns that doesn't start with A, and write all data in columns that do start with A following the advise from here:

[How to groupby and pivot a dataframe with non-numeric values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61318800/how-to-groupby-two-columns-while-assigning-aggregated-rows-to-new-columns-and/61319423#61319423)

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mind to add a [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Comment: I made it a bit more simple to focus on the problem at hand. Is that okay?

Comment: Do you mean `df_2`?

Comment: I corrected it now. Yes. It was just to give it another name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there are some problem when you assign index and values. I did a [mcve](/help/mcve) and the following code is working in my case

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4),
                  columns=["A1", "A2","B1", "B2"])

cols_index = list(df.columns[~df.columns.str.startswith('A')])
cols_values = list(df.columns[ df.columns.str.startswith('A')])

pd.pivot_table(df, index=cols_index, values=cols_values)
```

In case for your `df` this doesn't work try to add a sample of your data.

Comment: Ok, I now know what you mean by mcve. Thanks for the help. I will try it out.

Comment: It gives me the error "TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'datetime.datetime'"

Comment: I understand, but how do I make that if I have 198 columns and 4080 rows? Not sure how I can recreate a dataset different from the one you made. Would it make a difference that some columns have string data, and some data take values NaN?