# Combine table in one table

Tags: mysql, join, select, command

I have 3 tables :

Employee table:

| Emp_Id | E_Name |
| --- | --- |
| e-001 | John |
| e-002 | Hanson |

Addition table :

| Emp_Id | A_Name | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| e-001 | Basic | 100 |
| e-001 | Bonus | 15 |
| e-002 | Basic | 150 |
| e-002 | Bonus | 20 |

Deduction table :

| Emp_Id | D_Name | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| e-001 | Insurance | 5 |
| e-001 | loan | 10 |
| e-002 | Insurance | 5 |
| e-002 | loan | 0 |

what I need is to combine 3 table into one table like this:

| Emp_Id | Basic | Bonus | Insurance | Loan |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| e-001 | 100 | 15 | 5 | 10 |
| e-002 | 150 | 20 | 5 | 0 |

is that possible in mysql? please help me, thank you.

Comment: Similar to this question, you might be able to use the technique describe here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37787289/how-to-merge-two-tables-and-transpose-rows-to-columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t0.emp_id, 
       t11.value basic, t12.value bonus,
       t21.value insurance, t22.value loan
FROM employee t0
LEFT JOIN addition  t11 ON t0.emp_id = t11.emp_id AND t11.a_name = 'Basic'
LEFT JOIN addition  t12 ON t0.emp_id = t12.emp_id AND t12.a_name = 'Bonus'
LEFT JOIN deduction t21 ON t0.emp_id = t21.emp_id AND t21.d_name = 'Insurance'
LEFT JOIN deduction t22 ON t0.emp_id = t22.emp_id AND t22.d_name = 'Loan'
```

Comment: Hi @Akina, thank you for your answer, it works great if the addition table and deduction table has static row, but how to make it dynamic based on addition table and deduction table row? for example if I add new record 'over_time' on addition table, then the select query should show the column  dynamically. thank you.

Comment: @Pramono The thing which you need in is well-known as "pivot". If the list of possible categories names is dynamic then you must use special technique which can build needed output. Its output structure is dynamic, so you'd use dynamic SQL (PREPARE statement) in stored procedure. Search SO by provided term - there is a lot of solutions.

Comment: ok @Akina, I'll try to search more about pivot. thank you for your info!

Comment: @Pramono From the other side I'd recommend you to select "flat" data array and pivot it on the client side using its reporting subsystem. Pivot is not relational construction, and most DBMSs does not provide effective instruments for its creation.

Comment: ok, I'll keep it in mind, thank you for your recommendation.